# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg' while installing Docker

Tags: apt, repository, docker

I tried running the following command to set up a stable repository while installing Docker on my Ubuntu 18.04 server

```
    sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable
```

I get the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are missing the os package **python-apt**, install it via the following commands

```
 apt-get update 
 apt-get install python-apt
```

Please follow the official documentation for the install of the docker for a clean install
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/